# Redis service is not starting

Tags: redis

I built from source and installed Redis on my system following [this digital-ocean guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-redis-on-ubuntu-16-04). But after running

```
$ sudo systemctl status redis
```

I get this failed status report.

> ● redis.service - Redis In-Memory Data Store    
> Loaded: loaded
>   (/etc/systemd/system/redis.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled) 
>   
> Active: **failed**(Result: exit-code) since Tue 2018-04-03 01:51:54
>   +0530; 1s ago   
> Process: 24974 **ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf** (code=exited, **status=203/EXEC**)  
> Main PID: 24974
>   (code=exited, **status=203/EXEC**)
>
> - systemd[1]: redis.service: Unit entered failed state.
> - systemd[1]: redis.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
> - systemd[1]: redis.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
> - systemd[1]: Stopped Redis In-Memory Data Store.
> - systemd[1]: **redis.service: Start request repeated too quickly.**
> - systemd[1]: Failed to start Redis In-Memory Data Store.
> - systemd[1]: redis.service: Unit entered failed state.
> - systemd[1]: redis.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

My system is Ubuntu 17.10 x64

Answer (score 5):

Check by typing this:

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf
```

It will tell you where you're wrong.

Comment: I'm using centos 7 and command is: ```sudo /usr/bin/redis-server /etc/redis.conf```

Answer (score 3):

I always have this kind of trouble. Usually I use the tool on utils package and this problem is solved.

```
sudo /tmp/redis-stable/utils/install_server.sh
```

I guess this approach a good way.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please tell me what happen when you exec the following command? `redis-server`

Please don't forget give more information about your `redis.conf` file because the root of problem could be there and redis logs too, you can add the following line in your config file to get some error logs.

```
logfile /path/to/my/log/file.log
```

After that you should restart or reload the service to get additional information

I hope this information help you!

Comment: I'm getting the error `systemctl start redis
Job for redis.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status redis.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
` if I include logfile entry in `redis.conf`

Answer (score 0):

I have same error and I solved that problem by fixing dir in redis.conf(I guess that is the directory for dump.rdb).

`dir /some/directory`

So dump.rdb can be located in the directory that the user have permission.